# boost::bimap skips insertion

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

In a scenario there are two producer and two consumer using boost::bimap object, where One producer inserts data in the bimap object another producer updates the same if found.

There are three classes and one boost::bimap involved in doing the above said task.

Class A - Contains some strategies to produce data and runs on separate thread.There can be multiple separate copy of "Class A" running based on the number of clients connected.

Class B - Forwards data to a third party server based on any data pushed in a holder. This class has  single instance.

Class C - It receives data from third party server and runs on a separate thread. This class has  single instance.

boost::bimap In_bimap - To seggregate data based on UserID ,in "Class A" a hashkey is being generated from a "struct X" and that contains Token Number, Price ,Qty & Buy_Sell indicator and stored as key with UserID as value;

After generating and storing hash in In_bimap the struct needs to be pushed to the server which is being done by class B. Hence the "struct X" is being pushed in a vector.

Once the third party server receives the data it responds with the same packet by adding on more element to it and that is OrderNumber. This packet is being received by Class C which after receiving generates HashKey based on "Token Number, Price ,Qty & Buy_Sell indicator". Out of 100 i can say that 96 times it works perfect i search for the Key in In_bimap and get the UserID to push data ahead but quite a few times Key it not found in the bimap.

My logging says that "Class A" generated HashKey and tried to insert the data but the count before and after the insertion were the same. That means no data was inserted.

The definition of In_bimap:

```
typedef boost::bimap< long,boost::bimaps::multiset_of< int>> In_bimap;
```

In_bimap _InPF;

```
typedef In_bimap::value_type In_position;
```

Here second part of bimap has multiset because same key can be ganarated from the other clients too but userid will be unique.That means for same Key it may hold multiple UserID.

Method i am using to add record to In_bimap :

```
void AddRecord(long Key, int Value)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);

     _InPF.insert(In_position(Key,Value));


     lock.unlock();
    the_condition_variable.notify_one();


}
```

Method used to retreive data from In_bimap:

```
int GetRecord(long Key)
{


    int popped_value;

    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);



    In_bimap::left_map& AllKey = _InPF.left;
    auto iter_pair = AllKey.equal_range(Key);
    for (auto it = iter_pair.first; it != iter_pair.second;++it)
    {
        popped_value = it->second;

        break;
    }
    if(popped_value ==0 )
    {
        cout << "No record found"<<endl;
    }
lock.unlock();
the_condition_variable.notify_one();


    return popped_value;
}
```

Since GetRecord returns zero if Key not found . User of the specific record doesn't get any intimation of what happened to the sent packet.

The HashKey generation routine was altered version of last example at [http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash]

Please help.

Comment: I don't think you're using your condition variable correctly. Where are you performing a wait operation on the condition_variable?

Comment: furthermore, I don't think your bimap is correct for what you want. your left set is constrained to a single instance. a second insert for an existing key will fail.

Comment: Your first point is correct I have missed that wait condition. I am trying to insert wait with condition. for your second suggestion should I add multiset on both part or is there some other way around?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are really trying to achieve, but if you want to store multiple events against the same customer id then clearly the customer_id must be allowed to exist more than once in the map - this implies multiset on the left hand side doesn't it?

Comment: I want to store multiple events against the same HashKey. That means same hashkey can have multiple clientid.

Comment: why against the hash_key? wouldn't it be more logical to store events per client? - using an unordered_set (i.e. hash set)?

Comment: It has been done against the hash_key because the Packet sent to Third party server does not accept any other struct other than the one described above "struct X" with elements "Token Number, Price ,Qty & Buy_Sell indicator " and once the packet returns with OrderNumber added to it (from the third party server) I use the elements (Token Number, Price ,Qty & Buy_Sell indicator ) to generate the same hashkey and come to know which client's order was it and then i push it back to the client.

Comment: but hashes are not unique. don't you really want to be generating a sequence number?

Comment: I can not use sequence number as the sender and receiver sequence number are not always same and if any rejection occurs from the exchange end the sequence number may change, and my need is to identify the packet received from the stock exchange and find the suitable client for it and transfer the same to them. So either i can use lambda to search for the UserID based on Token ,price,Qty and side or use something which can be regenerated from the structure received because for the Order confirmation exchange sends the same packet back by adding order number to it.

Comment: furthermore, I am unable to use lambda because of the restriction of not to move to c++11. So , i found generating hashkey from the structure would be a better way. And yes there may be duplicate keys if more than on user is placing order for the same token at same side/price and qty. That's why i am willing to hold multiple clientid for same hash_key by using multi_set. Please suggest if any other formula can work.

Comment: but the token number is the same in the request and the response right?...

Comment: Suppose out of 10 clients 4 have placed an order in TokenNo 45789. In them two have placed the order with 8 lot @ 22500 and  one has placed the order  with 2 lot @22495 and the last one has placed 8 lot @ 22490. Now once the response is received for token number  45789. Now i need to search for the Token which has price 22500 and qty 8 by looping or lambda. That looping is the thing i want to skip and lambda can be implemented using c++11 which is the restriction. In the case of Fix protocol i get an option to send remark which i can use further for searching client but here its not possible.